# I am facing a strange problem on integrating Admob into my Android Studio Project

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, admob, build.gradle

So I'm trying to implement admob into my android project. I am following Google's official guide for this purpose (https://developers.google.com/admob/android/quick-start#import_the_mobile_ads_sdk)
 but I am getting an error on adding this line into my build.gradle(Module app),

> > implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.1.1'

[image]
issue description :

> All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version
>   specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found
>   versions 28.0.0, 26.1.0. Examples include
>   com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:28.0.0 and
>   com.android.support:customtabs:26.1.0 less... (Ctrl+F1)  There are
>   some combinations of libraries, or tools and libraries, that are
>   incompatible, or can lead to bugs. One such incompatibility is
>   compiling with a version of the Android support libraries that is not
>   the latest version (or in particular, a version lower than your
>   targetSdkVersion).  Issue id: GradleCompatible

My Target SDK is API 14

My build.gradle(Module:app)
https://justpaste.it/684d6

Comment: Add your full gradle file in here also

Comment: why your target sdk is api 14?

Comment: mixed version error can be solved by adding all conflicting dependencies in your module level gradle file with same version for all

Comment: If you have some other modules in the application check their versions also, they might differ from each other

Comment: @RakshitNawani HERE'S my build.gradle(Nodule:app) : https://justpaste.it/684d6

Comment: @DharakBhatt myTargetSdkVersion is 28 and minSdkVersion is 14

Comment: @RakshitNawani How can I see versions of other modules ?

Comment: @DharakBhatt I am getting that error only on adding this line implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.1.1' , on removing it there aren't any error and app is running fine

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57198973/7254873 and backup your project before migrating

Answer (score 0):

replace with this.

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 28
defaultConfig {
applicationId "com.bitpix.tales"
minSdkVersion 14
targetSdkVersion 28
versionCode 1
versionName "1.0"
testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
release {
minifyEnabled false
proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
}
}
}

dependencies {
   implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:customtabs:28.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.1.2'

}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 0):

Just copy and paste error version shown in gradle. For this scenario it is `'com.android.support:customtabs:26.1.0 '`.

Implement this line in your gradle file it will solve the issue.

```
//add this line
implementation 'com.android.support:customtabs:26.1.0'
//change the version to your appcompat support version it will solve the problem
implementation 'com.android.support:customtabs:28.0.0'
```

compile gradle once. This error will be resolved.

Answer (score -1):

there is number of dependency in support library Bundle, this library have not same version, but you can run without resolved this error. your app run fine.

Comment: No , app crashes on start

Comment: but I have added this to manifest file :         <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.com.bitpix.talis"
            android:value="ca-app-pub-2090022710320891~14801239379"/>

Comment: try replace this  implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:16.0.0'

Comment: Now it don't crashes but still I can't show the ads , my xml isn't recognizing the 'ads' keyword : https://imgur.com/a/AnKvuPT