# 'ERROR: Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:29.0.1'

Tags: android, gradle, intellij-idea, build-tools, appcompatactivity

I want to try Intellij Platform for android development but even after fresh it shows gradle failures. Please help.

I have tried tweaking the line

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:29.+'
```

to some other versions but to no avail.

Here is my module level gradle

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:29.+'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

Here is my project level Gradle

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

The errors which I am getting while Intellij builds the gradles are

```
ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not find any version that matches com.android.support:appcompat-v7:29.+.
Show Details
Affected Modules: app


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not find any version that matches com.android.support:appcompat-v7:29.+.
Show Details
Affected Modules: app


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not find any version that matches com.android.support:appcompat-v7:29.+.
Show Details
Affected Modules: app


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@release/compileClasspath': Could not find any version that matches com.android.support:appcompat-v7:29.+.
Show Details
Affected Modules: app


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@releaseUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not find any version that matches com.android.support:appcompat-v7:29.+.
Show Details
Affected Modules: app


ERROR: Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:29.0.1
Affected Modules: app
```

Comment: try to update 

classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0' 
with latest version

Comment: Have you tried my answer?

Comment: I tried to update the gradle to 3.4.2 but now it shows a different error 

ERROR: Minimum supported Gradle version is 5.1.1. Current version is 4.10.1.

Please fix the project's Gradle settings.
Fix Gradle wrapper and re-import project
Gradle settings
@roshanposakya

Comment: yes @SumitShukla

Comment: Check my updated answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Migrate to `androidX` by going to:

```
Refactor->Migrate to androidX
```

[image]

Comment: Where should I write it ? ... I am total noobs

Comment: Yeah there is no android option .... only JavaFX, JUnit and Swing

Comment: yeah I got it ... I have selected migrate to android x and now it shows the references where I need to change the lines

Comment: after changing them it shows the minimum gradle version should be 4.1.1

Comment: Yes update the gradle version too!

Comment: yeah finally thanks ....solved it :D ... Thanx bro

Comment: Glad it helped!

Comment: Just one more thing .... how to like migrate to android x by default.... suppose whenever I start a new project or something like that

Comment: When you will create a new project tick checkbox of use androidx artifacts in android studio.

Comment: yeah got it ... thanx