# Failed to resolve: com.android.support:design:26.2.0 error in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-support-library

I am trying to follow a tutorial and it asks us to clone a project from GitHub. I have done this but when it runs in my Android Studio, I get two errors,

```
failed to resolve 'com.android.support:design:26.2.0'
failed to resolve 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.2.0'
```

I have looked this up on Stackoverflow and seems a common question, but I don't seem to be able to get it to work.

my current gradle files look like this,

module gradle file,

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.android.emojify"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.2.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

I know the sdkVersion needs changing as it says cannot be lower than 26, but I have reset to what was initially imported from github.

project gradle,

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {

        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

When I change the sdk etc to 26 I get the error,

> Failed to resolve: com.android.support:design:26.2.0
>
> Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.2.0

I have read on here about adding in,

```
maven {
    url "www.maven.google.com"
}

This doesn't seem to make any difference though.
```

Comment: Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57198973/7254873

Comment: Migrate to AndroidX, clean/rebuild project

Comment: There is no option to migrate to AndroidX, the only options are Junit and Swing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Failed to resolve: com.android.support:design:26.2.0
>
> Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.2.0

It's simply because the last version of support library 26 is version [`26.1.0`](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions?hl=ID#26-1-0). You better to use support library version 28.0.0 or either upgrading to AndroidX.

Comment: It is correct but in his gradle script there isn't 26.2.0, but just 25.2.0

Comment: Thanks, changing to sdk to 28 and support to 28.0.0 seems to have worked now. I know I am cloning old repositories from this tutorial and have never cloned an older version before. Thanks for your help.