# Gradle DSL method not found: 'exlude()' Possible causes:

Tags: android

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w565O.jpg)ERROR: Gradle DSL method not found: 'exlude()'
Possible causes:
The project 'ZinnerChat' may be using a version of the Android Gradle plug-in that does not contain the method[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n6LmM.jpg) (e.g. 'testCompile' was added in 1.1.0).
This works, but not further

Answer (score 0):

Go to line 31 and 32 and replace `exlude` with `exclude` , it should work.
It is function name from gradle and is spelled incorrectly in your project so gradle gives error.

Comment: implementation 'com.android.support:constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
Error

Comment: Is this an old project? If it is change compileSdk and targetSDK from line 3 and 8 to 27.
`compileSdk 27`
`targetSdk 27`

Comment: If this is a new project then please read my other answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57305268/could-not-find-any-version-that-matches-com-android-supportappcompat-v729/57305610#57305610