# How to fix 'ERROR: Failed to resolve: androidx'?

Tags: java, android, gradle, build.gradle

i back to work again to complete my application but when the application start syncing it gave me

> Failed to resolve: androidx Affected Modules:  href="openFile:D:/.android/Step View/Application/Source Code/app/build.gradle">app

I see a question like this but it didn't works for me. sorry for my bad english.

this is my gradle. app

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'gradle.plugin.com.onesignal:onesignal-gradle-plugin:[0.11.0, 0.99.99]'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.onesignal.androidsdk.onesignal-gradle-plugin'

repositories {
    maven {
        url 'https://maven.google.com'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.xcoder.stepview"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 28
        multiDexEnabled true
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.connection_light.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        manifestPlaceholders = [
                onesignal_app_id               : '6a2c7692-81ec-4d12-b973-6b78f71f380e',
                // Project number pulled from dashboard, local value is ignored.
                onesignal_google_project_number: 'REMOTE'
        ]
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-alpha01'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.6'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation 'com.github.kittinunf.fuel:fuel-android:1.12.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:17.1.2'
    implementation 'com.github.bassaer:chatmessageview:1.10.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-alpha3'
    implementation 'com.github.markushi:circlebutton:1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha02'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.5'
    implementation 'com.github.ybq:Android-SpinKit:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'commons-io:commons-io:2.5'
    implementation 'androidx.percentlayout:percentlayout:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:[3.9.1, 3.99.99]'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.connection_light:runner:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.connection_light.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57198973/7254873

Answer (score 3):

In my case it was caused by a typo in `build.gradle`:

```
//androidTestImplementation 'androidx  .test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0' // wrong!
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
```

I found the error by running the Gradle wrapper from the command line with the stacktrace option:

```
./gradlew clean build --stacktrace
```

Output:

> Caused by: org.gradle.internal.resolve.ModuleVersionNotFoundException:
>   Could not find androidx.  test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0.

Answer (score 0):

Try to update all com.android* to the available com.androidx* versions that you can.

Make sure you have...

```
android.enableJetifier=true
android.useAndroidX=true
```

Added to your gradle.properties.

Or you could just do

```
With Android Studio 3.2 and higher, you can quickly migrate an existing project 
to use AndroidX by selecting Refactor > Migrate to AndroidX from the menu bar.
```

https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate

Answer (score 0):

You are using both `support library` and `androidx library` in one project, that's the issue.

Change the support libraries to the preferred [AndroidX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51280090/what-is-androidx/55849025#55849025) library.

and also you can Migrate to AndroidX from Android Studio itself

Simply go to **Refactor > Migrate to AndroidX > Migrate**

add below code in `gradle.properties` file

```
android.enableJetifier=true
android.useAndroidX=true
```

more info for migration check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51280090/what-is-androidx/55849025#55849025)

Answer (score 0):

for me it was

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
```

which must be

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0-alpha01'
```

that means check versions and implement the last ones for each androidx you have.

Answer (score 0):

you most upgrade all base library

change it

```
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-alpha01'
```

to

```
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.+'
```

and

```
 androidTestImplementation 'androidx.connection_light:runner:1.1.1'
```

to

```
 androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.+'
```

and

```
 androidTestImplementation 'androidx.connection_light.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
```

to

```
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
```