# I am trying to upgrade my gradle 28 SDK to 29 but its show me this error

Tags: android

The error shown to me when upgrading the gradle my sdk is 28 but i want to upgrade be 9+ andriod version not support.

```
>ERROR: Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28
Show in Project Structure dialog
Affected Modules: app


>ERROR: Failed to resolve: com.android.support:design:28
Show in Project Structure dialog
Affected Modules: app


>ERROR: Failed to resolve: com.android.support:cardview-v7:28
Show in Project Structure dialog
Affected Modules: app


>ERROR: Failed to resolve: com.android.support:palette-v7:28
Show in Project Structure dialog
Affected Modules: app


>ERROR: Failed to resolve: com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28
Show in Project Structure dialog
Affected Modules: app


>ERROR: Failed to resolve: com.android.support:support-annotations:28
Show in Project Structure dialog
Affected Modules: app


>ERROR: Failed to resolve: com.android.support:exifinterface:28
Show in Project Structure dialog
Affected Modules: app


>ERROR: Failed to resolve: com.android.support:support-v4:28
Show in Project Structure dialog
Affected Modules: app


>ERROR: Failed to resolve: com.android.support:customtabs:28
Show in Project Structure dialog
Affected Modules: app


>ERROR: Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:29.0.1
Show in Project Structure dialog
Affected Modules: app


>ERROR: Failed to resolve: com.android.support:design:29.0.1
Show in Project Structure dialog
Affected Modules: app


>ERROR: Failed to resolve: com.android.support:cardview-v7:29.0.1
Show in Project Structure dialog
Affected Modules: app


>ERROR: Failed to resolve: com.android.support:palette-v7:29.0.1
Show in Project Structure dialog
Affected Modules: app


>ERROR: Failed to resolve: com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:29.0.1

Show in Project Structure dialog
Affected Modules: app
```

Gradle

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13-beta-3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:29.0.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:29.0.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:29.0.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:palette-v7:29.0.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:29.0.1'
    implementation 'com.balysv:material-ripple:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
    implementation 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:3.11.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:18.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:19.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.ads.consent:consent-library:1.0.7'
}


android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.1"
    defaultConfig {


        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.1"
        testInstrumentationRunner
        "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
```

Error

```
>Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28
    <a href="open.dependency.in.project.structure">Show in Project Structure dialog</a>
    Affected Modules: <a href="openFile:E:/Software house/APPS/Building Apps/App 3 YourRecipesApp Online/App Model/Recipes Master/app/build.gradle">app</a> 
    Failed to resolve: com.android.support:design:28
    <a href="open.dependency.in.project.structure">Show in Project Structure dialog</a>
    Affected Modules: <a href="openFile:E:/Software house/APPS/Building Apps/App 3 YourRecipesApp Online/App Model/Recipes Master/app/build.gradle">app</a> 
    Failed to resolve: com.android.support:cardview-v7:28
    <a href="open.dependency.in.project.structure">Show in Project Structure dialog</a>
    Affected Modules: <a href="openFile:E:/Software house/APPS/Building Apps/App 3 YourRecipesApp Online/App Model/Recipes Master/app/build.gradle">app</a> 
    Failed to resolve: com.android.support:palette-v7:28
    <a href="open.dependency.in.project.structure">Show in Project Structure dialog</a>
    Affected Modules: <a href="openFile:E:/Software house/APPS/Building Apps/App 3 YourRecipesApp Online/App Model/Recipes Master/app/build.gradle">app</a> 
    Failed to resolve: com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28
    <a href="open.dependency.in.project.structure">Show in Project Structure dialog</a>
    Affected Modules: <a href="openFile:E:/Software house/APPS/Building Apps/App 3 YourRecipesApp Online/App Model/Recipes Master/app/build.gradle">app</a> 
    Failed to resolve: com.android.support:support-annotations:28
    <a href="open.dependency.in.project.structure">Show in Project Structure dialog</a>
    Affected Modules: <a href="openFile:E:/Software house/APPS/Building Apps/App 3 YourRecipesApp Online/App Model/Recipes Master/app/build.gradle">app</a> 
    Failed to resolve: com.android.support:exifinterface:28
    <a href="open.dependency.in.project.structure">Show in Project Structure dialog</a>
    Affected Modules: <a href="openFile:E:/Software house/APPS/Building Apps/App 3 YourRecipesApp Online/App Model/Recipes Master/app/build.gradle">app</a> 
    Failed to resolve: com.android.support:support-v4:28
    <a href="open.dependency.in.project.structure">Show in Project Structure dialog</a>
    Affected Modules: <a href="openFile:E:/Software house/APPS/Building Apps/App 3 YourRecipesApp Online/App Model/Recipes Master/app/build.gradle">app</a> 
    Failed to resolve: com.android.support:customtabs:28
    <a href="open.dependency.in.project.structure">Show in Project Structure dialog</a>
    Affected Modules: <a href="openFile:E:/Software house/APPS/Building Apps/App 3 YourRecipesApp Online/App Model/Recipes Master/app/build.gradle">app</a> 
    Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:29.0.1
    <a href="open.dependency.in.project.structure">Show in Project Structure dialog</a>
    Affected Modules: <a href="openFile:E:/Software house/APPS/Building Apps/App 3 YourRecipesApp Online/App Model/Recipes Master/app/build.gradle">app</a> 
    Failed to resolve: com.android.support:design:29.0.1
    <a href="open.dependency.in.project.structure">Show in Project Structure dialog</a>
    Affected Modules: <a href="openFile:E:/Software house/APPS/Building Apps/App 3 YourRecipesApp Online/App Model/Recipes Master/app/build.gradle">app</a> 
    Failed to resolve: com.android.support:cardview-v7:29.0.1
    <a href="open.dependency.in.project.structure">Show in Project Structure dialog</a>
    Affected Modules: <a href="openFile:E:/Software house/APPS/Building Apps/App 3 YourRecipesApp Online/App Model/Recipes Master/app/build.gradle">app</a> 
    Failed to resolve: com.android.support:palette-v7:29.0.1
    <a href="open.dependency.in.project.structure">Show in Project Structure dialog</a>
    Affected Modules: <a href="openFile:E:/Software house/APPS/Building Apps/App 3 YourRecipesApp Online/App Model/Recipes Master/app/build.gradle">app</a> 
    Failed to resolve: com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:29.0.1
    <a href="open.dependency.in.project.structure">Show in Project Structure dialog</a>
    Affected Modules: <a href="openFile:E:/Software house/APPS/Building Apps/App 3 YourRecipesApp Online/App Model/Recipes Master/app/build.gradle">app</a>
```

Comment: you have to migrate project to AndroidX.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57198973/7254873

Answer (score 2):

In Android Studio, go to `Refactor->Migrate to AndroidX...`

Comment: If you migrated you wouldn't have anything like `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:29.0.1`. You would have something like `androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0`

Answer (score 1):

Following artifacts don't exist:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:29.0.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:29.0.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:29.0.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:palette-v7:29.0.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:29.0.1'
```

Last support library version is `28.0.0` as you can see [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions):

Update the `compileSdkVersion` and `buildToolsVersion` to API 29 but keep the support library at version `28.0.0`.

However, as you can see, support library is now frozen at version 28. So, it is somehow deprecated. So, another option is to migrate your project to `AndroidX`. It is basically the support library with a new name (putting in very simple words).

Comment: I have migrated to androidX. Can u let me know what are the latest versions are preferrable for the projectSupportLibraryVersion, projectMinSdkVersion, projectSdkVersion, projectBuildToolsVersion