# I get an AndroidX error when I add plugin to dependencies. What's the solution?

Tags: flutter

I get AndroidX error when I add add-ons to dependencies.

> logger: 0.7.0 + 2, open_file: 2.0.3 error when adding plugins.
>
> The Gradle failure may have been because of AndroidX incompatibilities in this Flutter app.
> See for more information on the problem and how to fix it.

Comment: please add error message

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the relevant sections of your build script so that others can reproduce the problems; see [mcve].

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57198973/7254873

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your application you must be sure to use only plugin that are aligned with androidX libraries, if not it can cause some problems.

Seem that **logger** and **open_file** are yet compatible with androidX, I suspect that you never read that ["AndroidX compatibility"](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/androidx-compatibility)

Consider to migrate your flutter application to AndroidX. And NOT forget to add

```
android.enableJetifier=true
android.useAndroidX=true
```

under you gradle.properties file.

Comment: android.enableJetifier=true
android.useAndroidX=true ,gradle.properties It was run:)

Comment: @KRALJESUS great!!